# Computing $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left( \cos\sqrt{ {2 \pi \over x}} \right)^x$

Tags: limits

I have tried to solve the below limit using the exponential formula and then applying l'Hospital but the problem turns hard to solve. Does anyone knows an easier way for it?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\cos\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x}}\right)^x$$

Comment: Hmm it´s seems like im having problems with lateX coding.

Comment: I uploaded in a photo because idk where is the error, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried the standard 'take the log and apply L'Hospital's rule'?

Comment: Did you mean to say the llimit as $x\to\infty$? Otherwise, where does  $n$ come in?

Comment: I think i can´t apply L'Hospital's rule in 1^inf undets.

Comment: @David That's why you take the log of it to turn it into $\infty\times0$ or $\frac00$

Comment: Yes sorry, i think someone changed, x to infinite

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt But if i use log rule the result i get is infty*1, so i can´t apply L'Hopital's. Maybe i'm wrong, just asking.

Comment: How do you get $\infty\times1$?  Perhaps it may help to write it out?  You probably forgot you have to take the log of something in there, so the result should be $\infty\times\ln(1)$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt God I'm retarded. Sorry i´ve been to many hours studying and my brain is going to explode. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No problem, and you aren't retarded.  Helps to write out your work though ;)

Comment: Now the alternative approach is to use series expansion and the known limit $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x) = x\log\left(\cos\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x}}\right)
$$
so that your expression is 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{f(x)} = e^{\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)}
$$
Now let $u=1/x$ so that we need to find
$$
\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\log\left(\cos\sqrt{2\pi u}\right)}{u}
$$
Now apply l'Hopital and the fact that $\lim_{z\to 0} \tan(az)/z = a$
to get
$$
\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\log\left(\cos\sqrt{2\pi u}\right)}{u}
=-\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\tan\sqrt{2\pi u}/\sqrt{u}}{1}=-\pi\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\sqrt{2\pi}
$$
giving a result for the original problem of 
$$
e^{-\pi}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Stop thinking L'Hospital's rule is the panacea for determining limits! Here you simply need Taylor's expansion at order $2$.

First, it is enough to have the limit of the log, $\; x\ln\biggl(\cos\sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi} x}\biggr)$. So set $u= \sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi} x}$: $u$ tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$, and
\begin{align} x\ln\biggl(\cos\sqrt{\dfrac{2\pi} x}\biggr)&= \dfrac{2\pi}{u^2}\ln(\cos u)=\dfrac{2\pi}{u^2}\ln\Bigl(1-\dfrac{u^2}2+o(u^2)\Bigr)\\&=\dfrac{2\pi}{u^2}\Bigl(-\dfrac{u^2}2+o(u^2)\Bigr)=-\pi +o(1)\to -\pi
\end{align}
Hence the limit we seek is equal to $\mathrm e^{-\pi}$.

Comment: Can you explain me where the square root is, please?

Comment: Without forgetting the square root, you would obtain a correct $-\pi$.

Comment: @David: Sorry, I forgot it… I'll update in a moment

Comment: Sorry, how did you do to remove the logarithm in the last part of the exercise?

Comment: I used Taylor's expansion for $\ln(1-x)$: $\;-x-\dfrac{x^2}2-\dfrac{x^3}3-\dotsm$, at order $1$, and substituted $\dfrac{u^2}2$ to $x$.

Comment: I still do not understand sorry. Are you applying the Taylor series twice?

Comment: You composed   Taylor's expansion for cosine (at order $2$) with the expansion for $\ln(1-x)$ at order $1$, so as to obtain an expansion at order $2$ for the composition $\ln(\cos u)$. Composition of Taylor's series corresponds to composition of functions.

Comment: **Stop thinking L'Hospital's rule is the panacea for determining limits!** This most exact and most useful piece of advice, widely shared in the mathematical world, is probably what got this excellent answer two downvotes. If these reactions are not an example of psychological refusal of reality, I do not know what is.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}x}=1-2\sin^2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}$$

and

$$x=\frac{\pi\left(\dfrac{\sin\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2x}}}{\sqrt{\dfrac\pi{2x}}}\right)^2}{2\sin^2\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2x}}}.$$

The quotient inside the parenthesis tends to one, and the limit is that of

$$\left(\left(1-2\sin^2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}\right)^{1/2\sin^2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}}\right)^{\pi(\cdots)^2}$$

or

$$e^{-\pi}.$$